# Baseball Player Hit Percentage Probability - At Least

Tags: probability

A very reliable baseball player is known to get a hit when at bat 43% of the time.

He is expected to have 105 more times at bat before the end of the season, and he is 40 hits away from breaking a league hitting record.

What is the probability of him breaking that record before the end of the season?

Comment: I assumed this question to be an at least question, with the answer being .8676 (at least 40 times out of 105 with prob .43) however, that answer appears to be incorrect. I do not know why?

Comment: Seems not too far away,  a bit on the high side. Don't know whether continuity correction is expected. If not, we need to find the probability that $Z$ is greater than $\frac{40-(105)(0.43)}{\sqrt{(105)(0.43)(0.57)}}$.

Comment: That would give me a probability of .8461? If you do not mind, would you please explain how you deducted that Z must be greater than the amount you specified? What is that law/equation/rule called?

Comment: It is the normal approximation to the binomial. But maybe you are expected to work directly with the binomial. Software will let you compute the probability of $40$ or more hits exactly.

Comment: Yeah your method gave me the same answer as the correct one. I will look into this method. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Since I did not know what method you used to ger the $0.8676$ I could not comment on it.  We certainly want the probability of at least $40$ in $105$.